# Need help iin java program to connect to oracle 11g

Tags: jdbc

// This is a basic example of java program to connect oracle 11g database. I want to get data from emp table

public class BasicTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:1521:orcl","scott","tiger");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select ename from emp");

        while (rs.next())

            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

        conn.close();
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }

}
```

}

After running above code , i am getting error description like

ERROR: incorrect usage. OracleSql (-transition  |   {  } )

Can Anyone Please provide the solution for the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this and update us

```
public class BasicTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin@localhost:1521:orcl","scott","tiger");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select ename from emp");

        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        conn.close();
        stmt.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);

    }

}
}
```